# Javascript error in IE (getElementsByTagName(...).item(...)' is null or not an object)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, getelementsbytagname

Looking to use the Accuweather pollen count google app, however it's throwing an error in IE.

Here is a link to the direct script:

> http://www-igprev-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/ifr?exp_rpc_js=1&exp_track_js=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwhapowllc.googlepages.com%2Fpollen.xml&container=igprev&view=default&lang=en&country=US&sanitize=0&v=45408d622dfd6df4&parent=http://www.google.com&libs=core:core.io:core.iglegacy:auth-refresh&is_signedin=1&synd=igprev&view=default

Here is the surround script in question:

```
        function setContent(url) {
        _IG_FetchXmlContent(url, function (response) {
            if (!response) {
                msg.createDismissibleMessage("Error loading location data. Please try again later.");
                echoDefault();
            } else if (response.firstChild.nodeName != 'error' &&
                parseInt(response.getElementsByTagName('citylist').item(0).getAttribute('us'))
                + parseInt(response.getElementsByTagName('citylist').item(0).getAttribute('intl'))
                + parseInt(response.getElementsByTagName('citylist').item(0).getAttribute('extra_cities'))) {
                mylocation = response.getElementsByTagName('location').item(0).getAttribute('location');
                url = 'http://whapw.accu-weather.com/widget/whapw/weather-data.asp?location=' + mylocation;

                _IG_FetchXmlContent(url, function (response) {
                    if (!response) {
                        msg.createDismissibleMessage("Error loading pollen data. Please try again later.");
                        echoDefault();
                    } else {
                        var tree = response.getElementsByTagName('tree').item(0).firstChild.nodeValue;
                        var weed = response.getElementsByTagName('weed').item(0).firstChild.nodeValue;
                        var grass = response.getElementsByTagName('grass').item(0).firstChild.nodeValue;
                        var mold = response.getElementsByTagName('mold').item(0).firstChild.nodeValue;
                        var airquality = response.getElementsByTagName('airquality').item(0).firstChild.nodeValue;
                        var airqualitytype = response.getElementsByTagName('airqualitytype').item(0).firstChild.nodeValue;
                        var airqualitystyle = '';
```

The error is reported from this line:

```
    } else if (response.firstChild.nodeName != 'error' &&
```

Works fine in FF/Chrome, but in IE I'm getting:

> Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; 3M/MSIE 8.0)
>   Timestamp: Fri, 5 Aug 2011 08:01:57 UTC

```
Message: 'getElementsByTagName(...).item(...)' is null or not an object
Line: 986
Char: 12
Code: 0
URI: http://www-igprev-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/ifr?exp_rpc_js=1&exp_track_js=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwhapowllc.googlepages.com%2Fpollen.xml&container=igprev&view=default&lang=en&country=US&sanitize=0&v=45408d622dfd6df4&parent=http://www.google.com&libs=core:core.io:core.iglegacy:auth-refresh&is_signedin=1&synd=igprev&view=default
```

Any ideas what's causing this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the relevant part of your code too.

Comment: The script is at the top link I posted (I'm kinda new to JS so don't really know what the "relevant" part of the code would really be).

Comment: No one should have to follow a link in order to help you (what if the link is not reachable in future? The question becomes meaningless). The relevant part would be the line where the error is thrown and the surrounding code. Anything this line of code depends on.

Comment: Okay - the reason I posted a link is because the actual file is huge. I'll add the line surround the error code to my original post.

Answer (score 1):

There is some weirdness in some versions of IE where *item(0)* returns the length of the NodeList, not the first item. Instead, just access items using the index:

```
...getElementsByTagName('...')[0];
```

Comment: Thanks, I've replaced the item(0)'s with [0], however I now seem to be getting "error loading location data, please try again".

You can check it out here: http://bit.ly/pSeSuC

Does work in IE now though.

Comment: Sorry, full of minified script. If you want me to debug that you may not like my rate. :-)

Comment: I'm afraid it's not my script Rob, it's one I pulled off Google gadgets from Accuweather! I am rather clueless with Javascript so wouldn't be in a position to comment, but I'll take your word for it. Just really looking to get it working in IE.